# Pytorch: create a mask that is larger than the n-th quantile of each 2D tensor in a batch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a `torch.Tensor` of shape `(2, 2, 2)` (can be bigger), where the values are normalized within range `[0, 1]`.

Now I am given a positive integer `K`, which tells me that I need to create a mask where for each 2D tensor inside the batch, values are 1 if it is larger than `1/k` of all the values, and 0 elsewhere. The return mask also has shape `(2, 2, 2)`.

For example, if I have a batch like this:

```py
tensor([[[1., 3.],
         [2., 4.]],
        [[5., 7.],
         [9., 8.]]])
```

and let `K=2`, it means that I must mask the values where they are greater than 50% of all the values inside each 2D tensor.

In the example, the 0.5 quantile is `2.5` and `7.5`, so this is the desired output:

```py
tensor([[[0, 1],
         [0, 1]],
        [[0, 0],
         [1, 1]]])
```

I tried:

```py
a = torch.tensor([[[0, 1],
                   [0, 1]],
                  [[0, 0],
                   [1, 1]]])
quantile = torch.tensor([torch.quantile(x, 1/K) for x in a])
torch.where(a > val, 1, 0)
```

But this is the result:

```py
tensor([[[0, 0],
         [0, 0]],
        [[1, 0],
         [1, 1]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = torch.tensor([[[1., 3.],
         [2., 4.]],
        [[5., 7.],
         [9., 8.]]])

t_flat = torch.reshape(t, (t.shape[0], -1))
quants = torch.quantile(t_flat, 1/K, dim=1)
quants = torch..reshape(quants, (quants.shape[0], 1, 1))
res = torch.where(t > val, 1, 0)
```

and after this res is:

```
tensor([[[0, 1],
         [0, 1]],

        [[0, 0],
         [1, 1]]])
```

which is what you wanted