# Binary mask of top n-th quantile in a batch of 2D tensors, but with individual n for each tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor A of shape `(100, 16, 16)` and tensor B of shape `(100)`, where 100 is the batch size. I want to create a binary mask of A that has shape `(100, 16, 16)`, where in each element (element has shape `(1, 16, 16)`) of the mask, the value is `1` if the element is greater than the computed quantile value, else `0`. Each element in tensor B indicates the percentile value for each individual element in A, in sequence. If B is simply a **scalar**, I can use:

```py
flat_A = torch.reshape(A, (100, -1))
quants = torch.quantile(flat_A, B, dim=1)
quants = torch.reshape(quants, (100, 1, 1))
mask = torch.where(A >= quants, 1, 0)
# quants will have shape (100, 1, 1)
```

The question is: if B is a 1D tensor of shape `(100)` like I said above, how can I compute the percentile value for each individual element in A? I tried the following, but the results did not look like what I expected:

```py
>>> torch.quantile(flat_A, B, dim=1).shape
torch.Size([100, 100])
>>> torch.quantile(flat_A, B, dim=0).shape
torch.Size([100, 256])
```

I think the result's shape should be `(100)`, so I can use `mask = torch.where(A >= quants, 1, 0)`, or maybe I misunderstand it?

For more context, this question is also the extension of the scalar B value question I had previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268152/pytorch-create-a-mask-that-is-larger-than-the-n-th-quantile-of-each-2d-tensor-i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using [`torch.quantile()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.quantile.html) function. Note that here I am using tensors of shape *(5, 2, 2)* instead of *(100, 16, 16)* for simplicity.

```py
import torch
# Generate some data of shape (5, 2, 2)
A = torch.arange(5 * 2 * 2).reshape(5, 2, 2) + 1.0
B = torch.linspace(0, 1, 5) # 5 quantile values for each element in A

Af = A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1) # flattens A to a 2D tensor
quantiles = torch.quantile(Af, B, dim = 1, keepdim = True)
quants = quantiles[torch.arange(A.shape[0]), torch.arange(A.shape[0]), 0]

mask = (A >= quants[:, None, None]).type(torch.uint8)
```

Here the tensor `quantiles` is of shape `torch.Size([5, 5, 1])` because it stores the thresholds for each quantile value in `B` for each element in `A` (or *row* in `Af`). Since we have 5 quantile values, we get 5 thresholds for each element in `A`.

For instance, `quantiles[i, j, 0]` has the threshold for `B[i]`th quantile of `A[j]` or `Af[j]`, and you essentially need the values `quantiles[k, k, 0]` for `k` in range of batch size or 5 here.

Now to satisfy the requirement that you need thresholds for corresponding quantiles in `B` and elements in `A`, simply index out the diagonal elements from `quantiles` and populate `quants` that has shape `torch.Size([5])`.

Finally to get the `mask`, compare `A` with the corresponding thresholds for each element. Note that this uses a broadcasted elementwise comparison with the thresholds. `mask` has the required shape of `torch.Size([5, 2, 2])`.

Comment: Although this code works perfectly, but can you optimize it further?

Comment: I'll look into it. But did you check if it is the bottleneck in your pipeline?

Comment: I just `timeit` with the code in the question I had before, and your method is slower about 0.15 ms, which I think is not the case why my code runs slow. Tyvm again!